# how to get `bq://project_id'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

hello everyone i perform some CSV data in google cloud automl tables , and they give me to fill this variable output_path = `bq://project_id' , but i don't know what is it , please if any one can help i will be appreciated a lot

```
# TODO(developer): Uncomment and set the following variables
# project_id = 'PROJECT_ID_HERE'
# compute_region = 'COMPUTE_REGION_HERE'
# model_id = 'MODEL_ID_HERE'
# input_path = 'gs://path/to/file.csv' or
#   'bq://project_id.dataset_id.table_id'
# output_path = 'gs://path' or `bq://project_id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bq is the command form google cloud for bigquery. please refer the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool. 
 It is the asking the output path, where you can store your output either in gstorage or in bigquery table.